# Overload Clipboard.SetText VB.net 3.5 (or how to copy 3-4 text box conents at same time)

Tags: vb.net, overloading, clipboard

I have a form where I require user input and when the user presses the "generate" key it will copy all the data from the relevant text boxes to the clipboard for them to enter the data in an external application.

At the moment i can only find out how to get the function to copy one text box at a time, and not string them into a sentence.

```
Private Sub Notes_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Notes.Click
My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(TextBox1.Text, TextBox6.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextDataFormat.Text)
```

The problem is that the function can no be overloaded. Can someone please confirm the function i can use (or provide me a sample code) for how to copy all text box contents to the clipboard?

This is ALL on one form

Comment: `SetText(TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text +...)` doesn't work for you? The clipboard only accepts one text value at a time, so it's pretty clear why your overload won't work. If you need multiple values, concatenate them; if you need to keep them separately identifiable, put a separator character between them and parse them back out on the receiving end.

Comment: Ken, Thanks this was what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The clipboard only accepts one text value at a time, so it's pretty clear why your overload won't work. If you need multiple values, concatenate them; if you need to keep them separately identifiable, put a separator character between them and parse them back out on the receiving end.

```
My.Computer.SetText(TextBox1.Text + TextBox2.Text + TextBox3.Text +...)
```